# how constructors are called and how objects are called

Tags: class, oop, object

how constructors are called and how objects are called. IF we have parent class and two child classes derived from it.If i call parent class in main method how the calling method will work.

Comment: Please show example code.

Comment: You didn't even put a language tag, so no one can answer that. Choose a language then do a tutorial for it, then come back if you have a real question.

Answer (score 0):

**Contractors**

- Default is with no arguments : `Person p1 = new Person();`
- Custom is one that have arguments (you create them) : `Person = new Person("Danny",34);`

**Methods**

- static will no need object instance for calling them : `string names = GetNames();`
- non-static : `string name = p1.GetName;`

in class that derived from other class you pass arguments to both of the contractors for initialize the object new Man("Danny","male"); in case that person class have name variable and man have the gender variable, man contractor will initialize his gender variable and will pass the name to person contractor

the methods should be virtual for giving you the option to override them in every object (if you need) if it will be not virtual that the call will be from the father class... the call is the same as i write

there is match more.. you should look (to big to subject)